# SQL Server 2005 Conditionally Assigning Variables IN SP

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, stored-procedures, conditional-statements

Here is a simplified version of a stored procedure I am trying to write in SQL Server 2005.

My question is this:

I have declared a variable `@docid` to which I want to assign the results of a query as I Iterate through my cursor, if there is not an exact match, then I want to run another query and try for the next best match.

I tried putting in a test that says `IF @docid IS NULL then BEGIN [second query]`. This does not work since the variable `@docid` will not be `Null` it will just retain the previous value until the conditions for the first query are met and it is assigned a new value.

So how can I say "If I try to assign a docid to the variable @docid, but there is no match based on the conditions in the query then run the next query instead or `set @docid=''"`? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
declare @docid bigint,
        @account varchar(30)

While @@fetch_status=0
BEGIN
   Select @Docid=Docid
   FROM printdata 
   WHERE Account=@account

   IF @docid Is Null --Docid Is never Null once assigned a value
   BEGIN
     Select @Docid=Docid
     FROM printdata 
     WHERE balance=@balance
  END
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need to use a cursor?  What is it that you're trying to do at a higher level?

Comment: I am extracting data from a temp table I previously created and combining it with Docid info from another table which I am then inserting into two new tables. SO I am going through the rows of my temp table 1 by 1 with the cursor.

Comment: From that description, I think we could find a solution without a cursor... which would probably be a faster / simpler solution.  Could I ask you to edit your question to include the temp table that you're starting off with, and what you would like to end up inserting into the two new tables?

Comment: Thanks, but in this situation I think a cursor is just what I need. I have to go through each row in the temp table and try to match up a payment amount and account number with a particular document in the documents table. A join won't work in this situation as the conditions by which I am selecting these documents vary from row to row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would just first initialize `@docid` to NULL - then it **will** be NULL if nothing is found:

```
declare @docid bigint,
        @account varchar(30)

While @@fetch_status=0
BEGIN
   SET @docid = NULL

   SELECT @Docid = Docid
   FROM printdata 
   WHERE Account = @account

   IF @docid IS NULL  --  @Docid *WILL* be NULL now if nothing is found!
   BEGIN
     SELECT @Docid = Docid
     FROM printdata 
     WHERE balance = @balance
  END
```

Comment: +1 - Makes more sense than my solution of putting it at the end of the cursor

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the suggestion, but here is the problem. It goes through the loop once and gets assigned the value 123 then it goes through the loop again and finds no match so it still has a value of 123 until it goes through the loop a 3rd time and finds a match and is now assigned a value of 789. If there is no match I want to run a different query not just leave the variable with the incorrect value 123.

Comment: @cloud311: no, not really - each time you go through the loop, `@docid` is **first** initialized to NULL .... or am I missing something......

Comment: @marc_s you are right. I spoke to soon. If you initialize the variable to NULL every time you start the loop it will work just as you described. Thank You